# Проверка двух форм на одной странице

Tags: javascript

На одностраничнике есть две формы. Как сделать валидацию каждой из форм через javascript?

Первая форма

```
<form method="post" action="/sys_files/orders.php" id="order_form">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="Client_name" name="name" value="Имя *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="Client_email" name="email" value="E-mail *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="Client_theme" name="theme_site" value="Тематика *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <textarea class="input-text text-area" cols="0" rows="0" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" id="Client_order_description" name="order_description">Опишите подробнее свой заказ *</textarea>
    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" name="Client_order_send" value="Заказать" />
</form>
```

Вторая форма

```
<form method="post" action="/sys_files/testimonial.php" id="testimonials">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Имя *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Ссылка на профиль в соц. сети *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div>
    <textarea class="input-text text-area" id="message" name="message" cols="0" rows="0" placeholder="Ваш отзыв *"></textarea>
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div>
    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" id="SendTestimonial" name="SendTestimonial" value="Выказаться" />
</form>
```

Код js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Устанавливаем обработчик потери фокуса для всех полей ввода текста
    $('input#name, input#email, textarea#message').unbind().blur( function(){
        // Для удобства записываем обращения к атрибуту и значению каждого поля в переменные 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var val = $(this).val();

        // После того, как поле потеряло фокус, перебираем значения id, совпадающее с id данного поля
        switch(id)
        {
            // Проверка поля "Имя"
            case 'name':
                var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/; // используем регулярное выражение

                // Eсли длина имени больше 2ух символов, оно не пустое и удовлетворяет рег. выражению,
                // то добавляем этому полю класс .not_error,
                // и ниже в контейнер для ошибок выводим слово "Принято", т.е. валидация для этого поля пройдена успешно
                if(val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val))
                {
                    $(this).addClass('not_error');
                    $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                              .css('color','green')
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }

                // Иначе, мы удаляем класс not-error, и заменяем его на класс error, говоря о том что поле содержит ошибку валидации,
                // и ниже в наш контейнер выводим сообщение об ошибке и параметры для верной валидации
                else
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                    $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Имя" обязательно для заполнения<br> &bull; длина имени должна составлять не менее двух символов<br> &bull; поле должно содержать только русские или латинские буквы')
                                               .css('color','red')
                                               .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                               .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }
                break;

            // Проверка email
            case 'email':
                var rv_email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
                if(val != '' && rv_email.test(val))
                {
                    $(this).addClass('not_error');
                    $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                              .css('color','green')
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                    $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Email" обязательно для заполнения<br> &bull; поле должно содержать правильный email-адрес<br> (например: example123@mail.ru)')
                                               .css('color','red')
                                               .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                               .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }
                break;

            // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
            case 'message':
                if(val != '' && val.length < 5000)
                {
                   $(this).addClass('not_error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                             .css('color','green')
                                             .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                             .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                    $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Текст письма" обязательно для заполнения')
                                              .css('color','red')
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                                              .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
                }
                break;
        } // end switch(...)
    }); // end blur()

    // Теперь отправим наше письмо с помощью AJAX
    $('form#feedback-form').submit(function(e){

        // Запрещаем стандартное поведение для кнопки submit
        e.preventDefault();

        // После того, как мы нажали кнопку "Отправить", делаем проверку,
        // если кол-во полей с классов .not_error равно 3(так как у нас всего 3 поля), то есть все поля заполнены верно,
        // выполняем наш Ajax сценарий и отправляем письмо адресату

        if($('.not_error').length == 3)
        {  

            // Eще одним моментов является то, что в качестве указания данных для передачи обработчику send.php, мы обращаемся $(this) к нашей форме,
            // и вызываем метод .serialize().
            // Это очень удобно, т.к. он сразу возвращает сгенерированную строку с именами и значениями выбранных элементов формы.

            $.ajax({
                url: 'send.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                    $('form#feedback-form :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('form#feedback-form :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('form#feedback-form :text, textarea').val('').removeClass().next('.error-box').text('');
                    alert(response);
                }
            }); // end ajax({...})
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Иначе, если количество полей с данным классом не равно значению 3 мы возвращаем false,
        // останавливая отправку сообщения в невалидной форме
   }); // end submit()
}); // end script
```

Comment: `id` форм у вас для его существуют? Указывайте их для функции валидации по очереди.

Comment: дело в том что я указывал $(document).ready(function( в этом месте ){ но не сработало, может не там ставил

Comment: Нам это не известно. Без публикации вашего кода это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Я привел код проверки